# How to make author name hyperlinked to its profile in node template

Tags: 8, theming

There is a variable `{{ author_name }}` in node.html.twig, it will print something like below:

```
<span>Your author name</span>
```

But I would like to print something like that:

```
<a href='/user/10'>Your author name</a>
```

How can I get this done in node.html.twig?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally `{{ author_name }}` already comes as renderable markup containing the linked author name. But there's also `{{ node.getOwnerId }}` (the author's user ID) and `{{ node.getOwner.label }}` (the author's user name) you could simply use to build the link yourself.

```
<div class="foobar">
  <a href="/user/{{ node.getOwnerId }}">
    <span>{{ node.getOwner.label }}</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Note you can easily inspect what variables are available for a template by installing the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) sub-module Kint and then in your template print `{{ kint() }}`, flush cache and reload. You now will get all available variables pretty-printed to easily find out which ones you could use to solve your problem.

---

To make that snippet a little bit more sustainable use the `path()` function to build the link target. By that also path aliases (built with [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) for example) will be taken into account.

```
<div class="foobar">
  <a href="{{ path('entity.user.canonical', {'user': node.getOwnerId}) }}">
    <span>{{ node.getOwner.label }}</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! {{ node.getOwnerId }} and {{ node.getOwner.label }} work well! By the way, {{ node.getOwner.label }} == {{ node.getOwner.getDisplayName }}

Comment: @Basic, `getDisplayName` is not identical, it is a processed version of the name/label, see [User::getDisplayName](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3AgetDisplayName/8.6.x)

Answer (score 3):

Use `{{ node.getOwnerId() }}`.

```
<a href='/user/{{ node.getOwnerId() }}'>Your author name</a>
```